# Function in Java8 how to acquire reference of Cls::func(Cls cls) returns Object;

Tags: java, function, java-8

I use following test cases to test java.util.function.Function.

```
public class TestFunc {

  public String nonStaticFunc1 () {
    return "nonStaticAndPara of fun1";
  }
  public String nonStaticFunc1 (TestFunc tf) {
    return "nonStaticWithPara of fun1";
  }
  public String nonStaticFunc2 (TestFunc tf) {
    return "nonStaticWithPara of fun2";
  }
  @Test
  public void testFunc () {
    Function<TestFunc, String> func = TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1;
    System.out.println(func.apply(new TestFunc()));
    // Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method nonStaticFunc2(TestFunc) from the type TestFunc
    // Function<TestFunc, String> func2 = TestFunc::nonStaticFunc2;
  }
}
/* OUTPUT
 nonStaticAndPara of fun1
*///:~
```

A Function always corresponding to TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1(void) returns String; I checked the Function source code:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
  R apply(T t);
}
```

It seems when the function's parameter is empty, java automatically import a class object into it. Then how can I get a TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1(TestFunc)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason for the methods not being static? To refer to a non-static method you'll need an instance of the class.

Comment: @Bubletan  Sorry , I'm confused. Then how to comprehend on "Function<TestFunc, String> func = TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1;" . I did acquire the reference of non-static method without an instance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is terribly wrong.

> java automatically import a class object

It's functional programming in an Object Oriented programming language.
It's necessary to know which object you're using or calling.

I'm no lecturer so let's leave the explanation for later and look at my modified code:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class TestFunc {
    private final String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public TestFunc(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String nonStaticFunc1() {
        return "nonStaticAndPara of fun1 (no further parameter): " + this.name;
    }

    public String nonStaticFunc1(TestFunc parameter) {
        // parameter is received but ignored
        return "nonStaticWithPara of fun1 (parameter is received but ignored): " + this.name;
    }

    public String nonStaticFunc2(TestFunc parameter) {
        // parameter is received and used
        return "nonStaticWithPara of fun2 (parameter is received and used): " + parameter.getName();
    }

    public void testFunc(TestFunc parameter) {
        Function<TestFunc, String> func;

        func = TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1;
        System.out.println(func.apply(parameter));

        func = testFunc -> testFunc.nonStaticFunc1();
        System.out.println(func.apply(parameter));
        // TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1
        // means
        // calling nonStaticFunc1 from the parameter as in `apply(parameter)`

        func = this::nonStaticFunc1;
        System.out.println(func.apply(parameter));

        func = testFunc -> this.nonStaticFunc1(testFunc);
        System.out.println(func.apply(parameter));
        // this::nonStaticFunc1
        // means
        // this.nonStaticFunc1(testFunc)

        // similarly func2
        func = this::nonStaticFunc2;
        System.out.println(func.apply(parameter));

        func = testFunc -> this.nonStaticFunc2(testFunc);
        System.out.println(func.apply(parameter));

        // func = TestFunc::nonStaticFunc2; // doesn't make sense, there's no such thing as parameter of the parameter
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFunc parameter = new TestFunc("param");
        TestFunc caller = new TestFunc("caller");
        caller.testFunc(parameter);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
nonStaticAndPara of fun1 (no further parameter): param
nonStaticAndPara of fun1 (no further parameter): param
nonStaticWithPara of fun1 (parameter is received but ignored): caller
nonStaticWithPara of fun1 (parameter is received but ignored): caller
nonStaticWithPara of fun2 (parameter is received and used): param
nonStaticWithPara of fun2 (parameter is received and used): param
```

I've left some comments in the code as notes to explain some fundamental logic. I hope you're familiar with lambda.

EDIT: reduce the number of objects in sample code
EDIT2: change how nonStaticFunc2 works (it now uses the parameter instead)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code and time. But I'm still confused. `TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1.apply(para)` equate to `para.nonStaticFunc1()` but `this::nonStaticFunc1.apply(para)` equate to `this.nonStaticFunc1(para)`. Then how to comprehend on  `R Function<T, R>.apply(T)` , is T a parameter or caller ?

Comment: By the way, seems if we want to refer a `void func(void)`. We must change `void` to `Void`.

Comment: `TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1` and `this::nonStaticFunc1` are _method references_.  I don't understand what you mean by `TestFunc::nonStaticFunc1.apply(para)` or `this::nonStaticFunc1.apply(para)`.

If you are new to method references also, then first stick with lambda. If lambda is not familiar either, try the classic `new` Object injection.

I edited the code again, trying to make it clear that there's only two TestFunc objects this time, and changed how fun2 works (to use the param instead)

Comment: @Shark if you want the return type to be `void`, you have to use an interface with an appropriate functional signature, e.g. `Runnable`, for no arguments, `Consumer` for one argument, or `BiConsumer` for two arguments.

Comment: @Holger Thanks a lot. I got this. I was a little bit muddled about void. Now `R Function <T, R>.apply(T)` confuse me. Base on Nin's code above, `T` is sometimes passed in as a parameter, sometimes as a caller.

Comment: @Shark I suppose, the term you actually mean is “*receiver*”. When you have the method invocation `a.method(b, c)`, then, `a` is the receiver of the method invocation and `b` and `c` are parameter arguments, but the entire invocation expression is a *function over* `a`, `b`, and `c`. Therefore, you can expression a function with three parameters whose evaluation will perform a method invocation on its first argument, passing the other two as method parameter arguments.

Comment: So, from a functional point of view, `a` is not special. But it is from an OOP point of view, which is the reason why you have the choice, use `TypeOfA::method` to express a function which will have the receiver as first argument, followed by all method parameter arguments, or use `object::method` to specify a pre-bound receiver object and get a function having only the method parameter arguments.

Comment: @Holger Your answer is great. This is exactly what I am confused about. I'm poor in English, but you guys are so kind, thanks again !